# Dynamic Test Class for Trigger in managed package

Tags: trigger, unit-test, deployment-api

**Problem**

Using a managed package and Metadata API, we are deploying a trigger class that calls to a global packaged class. We are deploying also the Test Class dynamically for the object where we are creating the trigger.

The deploy works right in almost every case but if the destination org has a before trigger that returns an exception because some data validation or whatever, our trigger doesn't get executed and our coverage is 0%.

Taking this into account, our deploy fails and we cannot create our trigger.

**Tried Workarounds**

1. Our test class uses a SmartTestDataFactory but if the validation is in the existing trigger, we cannot control the conditions.
2. Use @seeAllData annotation and query an existing record and make and update. When our app is installed in a sandbox, it will not work because the object could not have any data.

**Question**
Is there any option to cover our trigger code and create our trigger?

Thanks in advance